# how to add dynamic key value in rc-slider

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-redux

I am using rc-slider to display range bar in my page, I want to mark up some values on that. this values I am getting it from backend. so I am setting this value inside render method like

```
  var temp= this.props.Value;
     console.log('Value',temp);
    const marks = {

      temp: 'myValue'

    };
```

What I want to do is like this

```
var temp= this.props.Value;
         console.log('Value',temp);
        const marks = {
    temp:{
        style: {
          color: 'red',
        },
        label: <strong>'myValue'</strong>,
      }
}
```

but if I put hard coded value it is working fine. how should I add it? I may have missed basic es6 or react concept

Comment: Follow my answer, hope it will clear your doubt. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to creating a dynamic property in the object.Wrap the field in []

```js
 const marks = {
    [temp]:{
        style: {
          color: 'red',
        },
        label: <strong>'myValue'</strong>,
      }
}
```